# messed up shapefile attribute table text

Tags: qgis, shapefile, text

I have a .shp file from AutoCad imported to QGIS (using _MAPEXPORT > text in AutoCad) and this is what happens to text in attribute table - example:

{\Fsimplex|c0;O\Fsimplex|c238;Š\Fsimplex|c0; Dom\Fsimplex|c238;ž\Fsimplex|c0;ale
\H0.8x;Bistri\Fsimplex|c238;š\Fsimplex|c0;ka cesta 19
ID povezave 115006}

It seems it doesn't recognize that {\Fsimplex|... is a font definition. I went through some QGIS settings related to fonts and style but that doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn't a corrupt shapefile being generated by AutoCAD? Shapefiles do not support fonts. dBase-III was a standard long before character sets like UTF-8 were developed, and grafting encoding schemes into dBase is a very delicate, and often application-specific endeavor.

Comment: I'm a beginner in both QGIS and AutoCAD, that's why I'm asking. I also tried importing DXF file, same issue. I guess I'll have to search for a solution in AutoCAD. 
Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a AutoCAD specific rule, the Shapefile format knows no such definitions. You could try to split up the "garbage" into readable values and then use data-defined text styling based on it.

Comment: You get the same garbage out of QGIS with `Project -> DXF Export` on a layer with labels.

Comment: Yes, garbage text appears both in DXF and SHP and other GIS software aswell (tried svGIS).  How do I split up the text into readable values you mentioned? With regular expressions in Expression dialog?
I need this text because I'm exporting to KML which needs to show the text defined for certain points but with this garbage on the way it's pretty much useless.

Comment: regex or substring operations to create new fields I would say.